# What does @@ ("at at") mean in ES6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've noticed `@@` used in a [few](https://blog.domenic.me/es6-iterators-generators-and-iterables/) [pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) about new ES6 features, but I don't know what exactly it means (whether it's actually syntax or just some kind of documentation convention). And it's hard to google. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Can we agree that well-known symbols are now more well known? :)

Comment: It's an internal (spec-only) convention, and [it's going to change](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1314)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`@@` describes what's called a well-known symbol. (Note that it isn't actually valid syntax in JS.) According to the ES6/ES2015<sup>1</sup> [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols):

> Well-known symbols are built-in Symbol values that are explicitly referenced by algorithms of this specification. They are typically used as the keys of properties whose values serve as extension points of a specification algorithm. Unless otherwise specified, well-known symbols values are shared by all Code Realms (8.2).

Code Realms refer to different instances of a JavaScript environment. For example, the Code Realm of the root document would be different to that of JavaScript running in an `<iframe>`.

An example of where it matter what code realm an object comes from is when trying to use `instanceof` to determine whether an object is an array (hint: it won't work if it's from another frame). To avoid these kinds of issues from popping up with symbols, they are shared so that references to (say) `@@toString` will work no matter where the object came from.

Some of these are exposed directly through the `Symbol` constructor, for example, `@@toPrimitive` is exposed as `Symbol.toPrimitive`. That can be used to override the value produced when attempting to convert an object to a primitive value, for example:

```
let a = { [Symbol.toPrimitive]: () => 1 };
console.log(+a); // 1
console.log(a.valueOf()); // (the same object)
console.log(a.toString()); // "[object Object]"
```

In general, symbols are used to provide unique properties on an object which cannot collide with a random property name, for example:

```
let a = Symbol();
let foo = { [a]：　1　};
foo[a]; // 1
```

There is no way to access the value except by getting the symbol from somewhere (though you can get all symbols for an object by calling `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, so they cannot be used to implement private properties or methods).

<sup><sup>1:</sup> See [this es-discuss topic](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/javascript-2015) for some discussion about the different names.</sup>

Comment: Notice that this doesn't fix cross-frame `instanceof`. A better example would be cross-frame iterable arrays.

Comment: @Bergi: I was trying to provide an example of a cross-frame issue in general, that's not really what I meant -- maybe I'll try and reword that.

Comment: @Bergi What does 'cross-frame' mean here?

Comment: @1252748 Across frames or iframes

Comment: @Bergi What would a cross frame iterable be then?

Comment: @1252748 Just an array instantiated by code in the other frame. Or even `new (window.frames[0].Array)()`/`new (iframeElement.contentWindow.Array)()`