# ES 6: Difference between Symbol.iterator and @@iterator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if there was a specific difference in implementing an iterator using the `@@iterator` function versus the `Symbol.iterator` one:

On MDN, there is a page on [`Array.prototype.@@iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator), yet in the examples itself, Symbol.iterator is used as the function name. Is this just the updated version and `@@iterator` is not valid anymore, or are both of them valid?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29492333/218196

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `@@iterator` function. That token produces a syntax error - it is [only used in specification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29492333/1048572) to denote a specific symbol.

If you want to use that symbol in your code, e.g. to access iterators on arrays, you have to use `Symbol.iterator`. Which is a property of the `Symbol` class initialised to have the value `@@iterator`.

Answer (score 11):

The ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) specification uses `@@iterator` to reference `Symbol.iterator`. There is no `@@iterator`, and wherever you see it, read it as `Symbol.iterator`.

I think (someone more familiar with the ECMAScript spec might be able to back this up) the reason `@@iterator` is used is because you need to access Symbol properties on an object using square brackets (`[]`), but most parts of the ES2015 specification (and documentation) used the more familiar dot-notion (e.g. `object.property` versus `object["property"]), and so`@@somesymbol` is used to keep things consistent.

See page 38 (marked as page 18): http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf