# Is an ES6 Symbol just a string with @@ appended to it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I create a Symbol:

```
Symbol('r2g.smoke.test')
```

Isn't that the same as `String('@@r2g.smoke.test')`, or no?

Comment: Short answer, no. What makes you think that?

Comment: @MatusDubrava: [The spec uses `@@...` to refer to symbols](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) and these names are often used in polyfills if the environment doesn't support symbols.

Comment: A symbol is its own primitive type, *along with* Booleans, Strings, Numbers, Null and Undefined.

Comment: very related: [What does @@ (“at at”) mean in ES6 JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29492333/1048572) and [Symbol.iterator vs @@iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29670320/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, while printing a Symbol may add `@` signs for human readability, an [ES2015 symbol](http://2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html) is very different than a string.

The key thing about `Symbol` is that every time you call it, you get a *unique* version of the symbol. The string that you pass in (e.g. `'r2g.smoke.test'`) is just a helpful description.

Some code to demonstrate:

```
~$ node
> const string1 = "hello"
> const string2 = "hello"
> string1 === string2
true
> const symbol1 = Symbol("hello")
> const symbol2 = Symbol("hello")
> symbol1 === symbol2
false
```

It is ***guaranteed*** that every time you call Symbol(), you will get a unique symbol that is different from every other symbol, EVEN if the description you pass in is the same

Comment: Actually, I think you might be wrong, `Symbol('x') === Symbol('x')` always, read the docs

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman He isn't wrong `Symbol('x') !== Symbol('x')`, always. That's in contrast to `Symbol.for('x') === Symbol.for('x')` which should be avoided when possible for the same reasons that global variables should be avoided.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for

Answer (score 3):

No, a Symbol with a description of `r2g.smoke.test` is not related in any way to the string `@@r2g.smoke.test`. [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol)'s in general are nothing like strings.

Comment: right an object can take only a number or string as a key, so symbols must be able to be stringifiable, etc

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Objects can only have strings or symbols as properties. They cannot have numbers. Anything that isn't a string or symbol is coerced to a string before being used as a key: `var obj = {}; obj[1] = 'test'; Object.keys( obj ).forEach( key => console.log( key, typeof key ) );` outputs `1 string`. Unlike numbers (and all other types), symbols are not converted to strings when used as object properties, since that would mostly defeat the purpose  of them.