# What is the meaning of double at sign (@@) before a symbol name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the context of ES6 symbols, it's often seen that double at sign (`@@`) is placed before a symbol name. Is it just another way to reference a built-in symbol? However, using it in code causes

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: can you show an example of where you saw this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered before: [What does @@ ("at at") mean in ES6 JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492333/what-does-at-at-mean-in-es6-javascript)

I am gonna leave this article here too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

A summary quote from the spec:

> Well-known symbols are built-in Symbol values that are explicitly referenced by algorithms of this specification. They are typically used as the keys of properties whose values serve as extension points of a specification algorithm. Unless otherwise specified, well-known symbols values are shared by all Code Realms (8.2).

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: If a question is a clear duplicate, best to flag it as a duplicate and leave it at that. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/220438

Comment: riiiight, actually didn't know, thanks

Comment: I found this answer quite helpful, especially the Mozilla docs link

Comment: I still don't understand what is well know symbol. It is so badly named.