# @@iterator- Javascript - what is it really?

Tags: javascript

What is actually `@@iterator`. Is this a symbol literal or something? I see it mentioned in many tutorials but no one seems to explain what kind of animal it is really.

Comment: Might also be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492333/what-does-at-at-mean-in-es6-javascript

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused, so it is not part of the Javascript Syntax but they still use it widely to refer to the Symbol.iterator symbol constant?! Is that right?

Comment: yes, the @@ isn’t part of the JS syntax, it’s more just a notation used by the spec “within this specification a well-known symbol is referred to by using a notation of the form @@name” - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), a well-known symbol.

The `@@` naming is a convention used in the javascript language specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols

Comment: But @@ is this part of the Javascript Syntax at all?

Comment: Edited my answer it's just a convention