# How can I include repeated @ symbols in JSX text content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I used an ascii art generator and it gave me an output in HTML. I then used a HTML to JSX converter and it gave me an output, which I put in a div in JSX. When it compiles it gives an error of

> Syntax error: Invalid identifier @@XSXX. (33:5287) (33:5287)

That line is

```
<span style={{color: '#000', backgroundColor: '#555'}}>@@XSXX</span>
```

It only seems to happen on chunks containing '@@'.
Does this have some custom behaviour in react (JSX) and how can I fix this?
It is not the first chunk.

Comment: Can we see the entire component? Hard to tell with just a line.

Comment: The component is 200 lines and at least a million characters. Can I paste that in without it being interpreted as spam?

Comment: I do not think it is a React-related problem; please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492333/what-does-at-at-mean-in-es6-javascript

Comment: You may want to use a binning service like [SourceBin](https://sourceb.in/) and share the link. I think your ASCII art has some special HTML characters like `<` or `>` that confuse the parser.

Comment: @secan `@@xxx` is only used in the spec or formal documentation. It's not a thing you can use in JavaScript.

Comment: All of the code pasting sites give a file too large error @caTS but this is the raw source code on github. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Westsi/portfolio/master/src/art.js

Comment: @isherwood I tried with one @ symbol and that did not cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to render the jsX like `@@XSXX` you'll get an

> `Invalid identifier @@XSXX`

---

You should not render it as jsX, but rather as a string:

```
<span style={{color: '#000', backgroundColor: '#555'}}>{'@@XSXX'}</span>
```